# Are there Martians on Arrowverse Earth 1?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, martian-manhunter

In the trailer for the DC superhero shows airing on the CW for 2016 (called the "Superhero Fight Club 2.0"), John Diggle is startled at Hank Henshaw shape-shifting into J'onn J'onzz.
His reaction seems to indicate that there is not a J'onn J'onzz or other martian counterpart on Earth 1.

But what about Mars?  Is the "Earth 1" Mars inhabited by martians or is it void of life?

Comment: In any universe, how many people do you think know the existence of Martians? Why is Diggle's reaction surprising?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm not sure what you are trying to get at, since neither question seems to clarify my initial question. But my answers are below.
1) Probably as many people know about metahumans on Earth-1 or Kryptonians on Earth-38.
2) If there were martians on Earth-1, Diggle would be far less surprised (for example, if elephants didn't exist on our earth and we saw an elephant, we would be much more surprised then we would be if we were familiar with elephants). The conclusion is that martians are not on Earth-1. The next question in that train of thought is "are there martians on mars?"